# What is the induced action on the Lie algebra of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group and $\Gamma$ be its Lie subgroup. If $\Gamma$ acts on $G$, does it also acts on the Lie algebra of $G$? Assuming that it induces an action on the Lie algebra of $G$ and that $G$ is the matrix Lie group how one computes the induced action. I came across this question while reading  [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82828062.pdf) by Baues. Any help is appreciated. I am new to linear algebraic group so pointing to where can I learn these stuffs will also help.

Comment: Well $G$ acts on itself by the adjoint action and this descends to the adjoint action on the Lie algebra and then the action of $\Gamma$ would just be the restriction of this action. If you are imagining a different action then the adjoint one then not necessarily